# Most important Linear Algebra theorems?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I was reading up on symmetric matrices and the textbook noted that the following is a remarkable theorem:

> A matrix $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable iff $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

This is because it is impossible to tell when a matrix is diagonalizable, or so it seems.

I haven't gotten to realize yet how important this is, but I will soon. What, in your opinion , is the most important linear algebra theorem and why?

Comment: It is a nice theorem which tells you a lot of facts in one shot.

Comment: It's not a linear algebra theorem, though :)

Answer (score 4):

The two main candidates are:

- The [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra), as popularised by Strang.
- The [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

From these, lots of important results follow.

Comment: I think "popularised" by Strang is an understatement. I think without Strang nobody would have noticed (or cared for such a formulation).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Really? Whyso? Because it had never really been conceptualized in such a way, or because it was seen as too simple? When I first learned the theorem, it seemed super obvious, but also quite conceptually useful. How had it gone so long without being made explicit?

Comment: @Arkamis: See [Intuitive explanation of the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/21144/18880) and the comments to that question, notably the one by Willie Wong.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I see. So that your earlier comment here is to make the point that, in a way, Strang "dumbed down" what was already a fairly straightforward result?

Answer (score 4):

Undoubtly the Invertible Matrix Theorem in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Well since linear algebra is basically about studying linear functions in linear spaces, i would say the rank-nullity theorem. It basically limits the size of range in terms of the nullity, and vice-versa. THe nullity of a tranformation and the rank add up to the dimension of the space. I dont know if we can say which is the most important but this is a result worth understanding very well and it also has similar form in other structures.