# Column space of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, transformation, vector-fields

Prove that if $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix over the field $\mathbb R$ of real numbers, then $\mathbb R^n = \operatorname{Col}(A^T) \oplus N(A),$ where $\operatorname{Col}(A^T)$ denotes the column space of $A$ and $N(A)$ denotes the right null space of A.

Comment: Please give some completments about the idea you have. I once have been told this many times...

Comment: hint: consider the inner product and orthogonal complement subsapce of $N(A)$...

Comment: Essentially, this is the Rank-Nullity Theorem. Can you emulate the proof for that?

Comment: @Carlo Yes, it is right over any field.

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Here is one where I posted an answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21144/intuitive-explanation-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-linear-algebra Here's another thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318136/the-range-of-t-is-the-orthogonal-complement-of-kert