# Explanation $\ker(T^*)=(\operatorname{Im}(T))^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some misunderstandings about the claim :

$T: V\to V$ is an inner products space.

$\ker(T^*)=(\operatorname{Im}(T))^\perp$

I don't get why $(\operatorname{Im}(T))^\perp$ isn't $\ker (T)$ ? (I know that $\ker(T)=\ker(T)^* \iff TT^*=T^*T$, this is not that case)

I will be grateful for an explanation or example, thanks!

Comment: I wrote an explanation of this fact here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/467256/40119

Comment: @erez It is not true that $\ker(T) = \ker(T^*) \iff TT^* = T^*T$, but it is true that $TT^* = T^*T \implies \ker(T) = \ker(T^*)$. For example, the operator corresponding to the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1}
$$
does not satisfy $TT^* = T^*T$, but it does satisfy $\ker(T) = \ker(T^*)$.

Comment: @erez Regarding your question, you might find it helpful to consider the operator corresponding to the matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},
$$
which is given by $T(x,y) = (y,0)$. Note that we actual have $\operatorname{Im}(T) = \ker(T)$ in this case!

Answer (score 2):

Just compute.
\begin{align}
x \in \ker(T^*) &\Longleftrightarrow T^*(x) = 0
\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \forall y\quad \langle T^*(x),y\rangle = 0
\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \forall y\quad \langle x,T(y)\rangle = 0
\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x \perp \operatorname{im}(T)
\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x \in \big(\operatorname{im}(T)\big)^\perp
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a proof is good enough explanation, but this is what works for me.

Lets take $ v \in \ker(T^*)$, we want to show that $ v \in \operatorname{Im}(T)^\perp$
so let's take $ v_2 \in \operatorname{Im}(T)$ and we want to show that $  \langle v,v_2 \rangle = 0$.

$ v_2 \in \operatorname{Im}(T)$ so there is $u \in V$ such that $ Tu = v_2$.

$$ \langle v,v_2 \rangle = \langle v, Tu \rangle = \langle T^*v, u \rangle = (v \in \ker T^*) =  \langle 0, u \rangle = 0$$

On the other hand, if we take $ v \in \operatorname{Im}(T)^\perp$ and we want to show that $ v \in \ker T^*$, so we need to show that $T^*v = 0$

one way of showing it is using the norm.
$$ \lVert T^*v \rVert = \langle T^*v, T^*v \rangle = \langle v , T(T^*v) \rangle = (T(T^*v) \in \operatorname{Im}(T), v \in \operatorname{Im}(T)^\perp) = 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow T^*v = 0$$

It wasn't an example but I hope it helps.

Comment: Note: use `\langle` and `\rangle` for better angle brackets: $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Also: `\lVert` and `rVert` for better spaced norm bars: $\lVert T^*v \rVert$.

Comment: Thanks! I am still beginner in Latex, so I'm glad to hear any comments.